# attempt to index global 'love' (a nil value)

Tags: lua, zerobrane

Can anyone explain to me what should i do to solve the problem ?

```
function love.load()
      love.window.setTitle(TITLE) -- Change le titre de la fenêtre
      local imgIcon = love.graphics.newImage(PATH_ICON) 
      love.window.setIcon(imgIcon:getData()) 
      love.window.setMode(WIN_WIDTH, WIN_HEIGHT) 
    .
    .
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to select `LOVE` as the interpreter (`Project | Lua Interpreter | LOVE`) instead of the default Lua interpreter. The error you are getting indicates that the interpreter you are launching doesn't have anything assigned to the `love` variable.

Comment: i've already selected LOVE as the interpreter, but the problem is, i'm getting the following error and i don't know how to deal with it. I don't know where to find this executable !
- Error : Can't find love2d executable in any of the following folders: /Applications/love.app/Contents/MacOS, /usr/bin, /bin

Comment: You need to set `path.love2d`; see the documentation for details: https://studio.zerobrane.com/doc-general-preferences#interpreter-path

Answer (score 0):

First thing : did you install love2d ?

If yes: did you check that the path to love2d was set in zerobrane?

Answer (score 0):

Check if love2D is installed in the computer using command terminal

```
love --version
```

If not, Download and install love2D from https://love2d.org/

And if yes, try to compile and execute using command

```
love .
```

from the directory where FILENAME.lua file is saved.